# Stopping a SoundPlayer loop at the local level

Tags: c#, soundplayer

I'm working on setting up an alarm that pops up as a dialog with multiple sound file options the user can choose from.  The problem I'm having is creating a sound player at the local level that I can close with a button.  The problem I'm having is that the sound keeps looping when I close the form because the SoundPlayer doesn't exist within the button click event.

here's what I have:

```
 void callsound()
    {
        if (SoundToggle == 0) // if sound enabled
        {

            if ((SoundFile == 0) && (File.Exists(@"attention.wav")))
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer alarm = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"attention.wav");
                alarm.PlayLooping();
            }
       if ((SoundFile == 1) && (File.Exists(@"aahh.wav")))
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer alarm = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"aahh.wav");
                alarm.PlayLooping();
            }
     }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //alarm.Stop();  Only works if SoundPlayer declared at class level
        this.Close();
    }
```

Is there a way I can do what I want to do by declaring the SoundPlayer instances where I am?  Or is there a way to declare it at the class level, and still be able to change the sound file based on user settings?

Answer (score 1):

Why is this a problem?  SoundPlayer doesn't support playing more than one sound at the same time anyway.  Move it to class scope, override OnFormClosing event, problem solved.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  private System.Media.SoundPlayer alarm;

  protected override void OnFormClosing(CancelEventArgs e) {
    if (alarm != null) alarm.Stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a problem because this is my first time using SoundPlayer, and I"m still trying to figure it out.

It's telling me "OnFormClosing" requires a return type.  How can I go about getting that taken care of? I don't know what it wants.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Now I'm going to see if I can figure out how to get it all pieced together.  I'm still very new to C#, so this is all new to me right here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SoundMixer.stopAll();
```

or

```
SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
```

The SoundMixer class controls global sound, so it should stop everything in the same security sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell, I was playing with playing .wav files and started a repeating loop using the following:

```
$Playwav = new-object ('Media.SoundPlayer') $playpath1 
$Playwav.PlayLooping()
```

I stopped the loop inside Powershell IDE by Run Section (F8):

```
$Playwav = new-object ('Media.SoundPlayer') $playpath1 
$Playwav.PlayLooping()
$Playwav.stop()
```

FWIW, the .wav in my example was FPS Doug [takethatbitch.wav.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqjWTojGogo) So the runaway loop made me laugh.

Hope this helps.