# C# how to handle a flag with a thread depending on external conditions

Tags: c#, multithreading, audio, asynchronous

I'm a beginner with C# and I have the following problem. My idea is: I have some possible triggers [`water_level_threshold1`, `water_level_threshold2`]. If `water_level_threshold2` is active `water_level_threshold1` is false [threshold1=true means that the water level is between the two values]. Depending on the trigger I want to activate two sounds corresponding to two alarms. The conditions are monitored every few milliseconds and my alarms last some seconds. I need the sounds to be played asynchronously because I don't want to stop the water level monitoring. The water level can of course changes randomly. At the moment, for example for the first threshold, I wrote something like:

```
if ((!water_level_threshold1_sound_already_started) && (water_level_threshold1))
{
    using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Antonino\Desktop\water_level_threshold1_alarm.wav"))
    {
        player.PlayLooping();
    }

    // to avoid the sound to be stuck on its first msecs [sampling time]
    water_level_threshold1_sound_already_started = true;
}
```

[As far as I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916505/stopping-a-soundplayer-loop-at-the-local-level) a SoundPlayer can handle just a tune per time so they will not overlap. And moreover the loop ensures me that the tune will be played until in that state, as I want. BUT if I have a variation in time like:

```
threshold1 exceeded [alarm1 performs correctly]->
threshold2 exceeded [alarm2 performs correctly]->
** water level decreased then **->
threshold1 exceeded [no audio]->
threshold2 exceeded [no audio]
```

from the second occurrence on they will not work anymore because they are told to have already been started and since they are executed in different threads I couldn't find a way to make a thread say: "I finished my execution then I can put `water_level_threshold1_sound_already_started = false`" so that if I re-enter in this situation a new thread will be open and the alarm will play again

Any detailed suggestion and/or solution would be really appreciated

Thanks in advance to those who will try to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solved my problem as follows. Hope it can be helpful. I put `player_already_used` flag to see if it makes sense to stop the `player`. When a `threshold` level is reached we start `PlayLooping()`. Since we have the beginning stopping-player part we will not have an overlapping problem between more tunes if the level changes. Water thresholds variations pull up `trigger`s and these determine which sound will be played depending on the water level measured. I think this solution [for this particular problem of course] allows an easier handling of the threads because there is no need to add one or more `BackgroundWorker`s

```
var waterThresholdOld = waterThreshold;
//GetAlert returns a string
waterThreshold = detection.GetAlert();

if ((waterThreshold != waterThresholdOld) && (player_already_used))
{
    player.Stop();
    water_level_threshold1_trigger_enabled = false;
    water_level_threshold2_enabled = false;
    water_level_threshold1_sound_already_started = false;
    water_level_threshold2_sound_already_started = false;
}

if (waterThreshold == ("water_level_threshold1" + Environment.NewLine) )
{
    water_level_threshold1_trigger_enabled = true;
    water_level_threshold2_trigger_enabled = false;

    if ((!water_level_threshold1_already_started) && (waterThreshold != waterThresholdOld))
    {
        player = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Antonino\Desktop\water_level_threshold1_alarm.wav");
        {
            player.PlayLooping();
            player_already_used = true;
        }

        // to avoid the sound to be stuck on its first msecs [sampling time]
        water_level_threshold1_sound_already_started = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A BackgroundWorker may helps in this situation. 
in DoWork event you introduce your operation and with checking the IsBusy property you can check weather it's running or not.
Good Luck.

Comment: in the meanwhile thank you because I didn't know the background worker and seems very very interesting. Then my question is: since "The PlayLooping method plays and loops the sound using a new thread" if I use the background worker and inside DoWork I ask to play the tune using PlayLooping will I have a thread in a thread?

Comment: That's right my friend. Since you need more control on the thread maybe using it is useful here. SoundPlayer.PlaySync does not use a thread and might be helpful.

Comment: unfortunately I can't use a PlaySync otherwise I would have a time issue, i.e. sample1->playSync would block for some seconds the main program with a sample2,3,4, etc. coming after sample1 with a distance of just few msecs... that's the problem! anyway thanks a lot for the interest, I really appreciated your help

Comment: @Antonino Yes my friend It's sync but since you're calling it inside a background worker not only you won't sense any delay but you can also easily check when it's done an rerun it again.

Comment: thank you very much, at the end I solved as you will see in the answer but thanks a lot because I learnt something new